# Eliminate title/author foot but keep header

Tags: beamer

I am using theme Boadilla in a beamer presentation in overleaf and I would like to remove the title, author and date boxes at the foot while keeping the header that I highlight in yellow in the picture. The rectangle right below of a lighter blue should also be removed.

[image]

That's my code:

```
% Latex template: mahmoud.s.fahmy@students.kasralainy.edu.eg
% For more details: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Beamer

\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}                    % Document class
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}            % Set encoding

\mode<presentation>                     % Set options
{
  \usetheme{default}                    % Set theme
  \usecolortheme{default}               % Set colors
  \usefonttheme{default}                % Set font theme
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] % Set caption to be numbered
}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{title in head/foot}{}
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{miniframes} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=gray} %<<<<<<<

%\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{} 
% Uncomment this to have the outline at the beginning of each section highlighted.
%\AtBeginSection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame}{Outline}
%    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
%  \end{frame}
%}

\usepackage{graphicx}                   % For including figures
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % For table rules
\usepackage{hyperref}                   % For cross-referencing

\title{Title for a minimal beamer presentation} % Presentation title
\author{}                               % Presentation author
\institute{}                    % Author affiliation
\date{\today}                                   % Today's date  

\begin{document}

% Title page
% This page includes the informations defined earlier including title, author/s, affiliation/s and the date
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please put your tex code.

Comment: Added. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}` to redefine the footline.

If you don't like the light blue subsection bar in the headline, don't set it to true: `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}`

Some other comments about your code:

- you should not use the `utf8x` option of `inputenc` with a current latex version. Use `utf8` instead -- or just remove the package as `inputenc` is loaded with the `utf8` option by default
- you don't need to load the `default` theme, as the name says, they are default
- No need to redefine the `navigation symbols` three times
- no need to use `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]` twice
- you don't need to load `graphicx` or `hyperref` in a beamer document, beamer loads them for you
- `\date{\today}` is not necessary, that's what the date will show by default

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}                    % Document class
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % For table rules

\title{Title for a minimal beamer presentation} % Presentation title
\author{}                               % Presentation author
\institute{}                    % Author affiliation

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
  content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]